# iPhone lock screen/multitasking bar audio controls don't work

Tags: iphone, ios

From time to time (in fact very often) my iPhone will stop displaying the lock screen "now playing" info, and subsequently the controls won't be there.

I can still start the music app playing something, but I can't pause or skip tracks.

The same thing can be seen if I try to use the multitasking audio controls (swipe "left" on the multitasking bar). The play/pause button won't stop audio playback. Can't skip.

Same problem with the headset remote buttons. Can often start audio playing (although what it'll play is random). Can not stop/pause, can not skip.

I've not been able to reproduce this reliably, but it happens often. The phone is in this state more than it isn't. A restart resolves this most times.

How to fix?

Comment: It's isnt rally an answer, but this happens to me ALL THE TIME on my ipad 2 32gb and it works every week or so.. But my ipad IS in fact jailbroken so that might be the problem.. The reboot worked but only for a few hours.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Possible Causes:

- Mobile substrate add ons on a jailbroken device
- Corrupt event handling events
- Loss of data with streaming services
- Accessory interference
- Airplay
- Older version of iTunes

Several things to try:

- If you are jailbroken try booting into safe mode (SBSettings Feature).
- If problem is with data streaming app then try the iPod app.
- If accessories are connected, disconnect them.
- If the problem persists, restore to the latest version of iOS and update iTunes.

Comment: Not jailbroken, not streaming, not using airplay, iTunes and iOS is latest (10.5.2 and 5.0.1), no accessory needed to trigger this.

Answer (score 0):

Do a hard reset. Hold the sleep/wake button and home button together until the phone turns itself off and keep holding the power button for a few extra seconds but let go of the home button as soon as the phone turns off.

Wait about 3 minutes. Turn your phone back on.

Now, open the multitasking tray and quit everything that is open.

If this works, then problem solved, if not, try a restore in iTunes. If that helps then problem solved, if not, go to the Genius Bar.

Comment: I'm attempting this. Did the hard reset as described yesterday. As with previous restarts of the phone the problem went away. Will update in a few days to see wether it "stays fixed" or not.

Comment: This didn't work. Soon only a full restore is the only thing I haven't tried. I'd prefer not to as it would take hours to do. Will see where I go from here.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug: only Apple can solve it with an update. It's not iTunes — it happens to any app you can listen music with, for instance I use YouTube but I can't pause/skip either, but I do remember that it worked till I fully turned it off. It could be that it changes if you turn off your iPhone and then turn it back on again. I would give this a try if I were you.

Answer (score -3):

I was facing the same issue. A restart fixed the problem.